# Where does PuTTY and VT100 start row and column?

Tags: putty, ansi-escape, vt100

I'm trying to figure out how the PuTTY terminal numbers its rows and columns.

Does it start from 0,0 or 1,1?

I'm using VT100 to set the cursor and it's important to send the right count.

I want to force the cursor location like this: `ESC[1,0f` and I expect it to set the cursor on the second row (starting from zero) and the first column.

Answer (score 0):

The separator is *semicolon* (**`;`**), not *comma* (**`,`**).

VT100 escape sequences number starting at **`1;1`** and generally will interpret a zero as a missing parameter, which makes that **`1`** as well.

Some terminal emulators may do unexpected things with an explicit zero, most handle missing parameters, e.g., **`\033[1f`** means the same as **`\033[1;f`**